# vue.js put focus on input

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input, focus

HTML

```html
<span :style="{ display : displayTitle }" @dblclick="showInput()">
  {{ node.title }}
</span>
<input :style="{ display : displayTitleInput }" type="text" 
       @blur="hideInput1" @keydown="hideInput2" 
       @input="changeTitle(node.id , $event.target.value)" 
       :value="node.title">
```

JS

```js
data() {
  return {
      displayTitle: "inline-block",
      displayTitleInput: "none"
    };
},
showInput() {
    this.displayTitle = "none"
    this.displayTitleInput = "inline-block"
},
hideInput1() {
   this.displayTitle = "inline-block"
   this.displayTitleInput = "none"
},
hideInput2(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        this.hideInput1()
    }
},
```

I am a beginner Japanese  web developer. I am not good at English, sorry.

HTML is in "v-for" (`v-for="node in list"`).

When double click text, it turns to `<input>`.

I want to make it possible to focus on input when it appears.

I tried this but it didn't work.

HTML

```html
<span :style="{ display : displayTitle }" @dblclick="showInput(node.id)">
  {{ node.title }}
</span>
<input :ref='"input_" + node.id' :style="{display:displayTitleInput}" type="text" 
       @blur="hideInput1" @keydown="hideInput2" 
       @input="changeTitle(node.id , $event.target.value)" 
       :value="node.title">
```

JS

```js
showInput(id) {
    this.displayTitle = "none"
    this.displayTitleInput = "inline-block"

    this.$nextTick(this.$refs["input_" + id][0].focus())
},
```

There was no error on console, but didn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much for a comment.  You mean like this? 
 this.$nextTick(this.$refs["input_" + id].focus())

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs[("input_" + t)].focus is not a function
    at VueComponent.showInput (sl-vue-tree.js?c536:8)
    at dblclick (sl-vue-tree.js?c536:8)
    at invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2023)
    at HTMLSpanElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1822)

Comment: I got this error(T_T)

Comment: Sorry, I was incorrect about removing the `[0]`. For some reason, the `$refs` property is an array

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your primary problem is that `$nextTick` takes a callback function but you are executing

```
this.$refs["input_" + id][0].focus()
```

immediately. You could get your code working correctly with

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.$refs["input_" + id][0].focus()
})
```

However, I think you'll run in to further problems and your code can be made much simpler.

One problem you'll find is that all your node inputs will become visible when double-clicking on any of them due to your style rules.

You could instead store an *"editing"* flag somewhere either on the `node` or in a separate object.

Below is an example that simplifies your code by...

1. Using the array-like nature of [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) when used within a `v-for` loop, and
2. Using the `enter` modifier on your `@keydown` event binding

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: [
      {id: 1, title: 'Node #1'},
      {id: 2, title: 'Node #2'}
    ],
    editing: {}
  },
  methods: {
    showInput(id, index) {
      this.$set(this.editing, id, true)
      
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.input[index].focus()
      })
    },
    hideInput(id) {
      this.editing[id] = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="app">
  <li v-for="(node, index) in list">
    <span v-show="!editing[node.id]" @dblclick="showInput(node.id, index)">
      {{ node.title }}
    </span>
    <input v-show="editing[node.id]" type="text"
           ref="input" :value="node.title"
           @blur="hideInput(node.id)" @keydown.enter="hideInput(node.id)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Oh my gosh!!! Thank you so much!!! You are a genius. I haven't used this.$set before. Very technical!

Comment: @nichika You're most welcome. `this.$set` is the same as `Vue.set`. You need to use it for reactivity as initially, `editing` has no properties so Vue doesn't detect new ones naturally. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 5):

The `autofocus` attribute is your friend:

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

Comment: (note: autofocus doesn’t work on mobile Safari) from Vue documentation.

Comment: alas, it's more fragile when SPA routing is in play, and only triggers the first time. (it fails to set the focus if you vue-route to another page and eventually back to here.) ref=... and .focus() is passing tests, though I haven't tested this on iOS yet.

Answer (score 4):

The way you use `this.$nextTick();` is incorrect. You should pass it a callback function.

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
    this.$refs["input_" + id].focus()
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/un65e9oc/7/

---

I'm not however sure how that array access is working for you, because as I notice, `$refs` is an object with the keys referring to the ref name.

[Edit: Thanks to @Phil's comment, above is clear.]

---

The above is the correct solution for your problem. Since you have already got that answer, I'll add something other than that.

The reason why you see this behavior is that because the reference you hold in `$refs` doesn't get updated when you change the visibility of the text box in your `showInput()` method. So when you call `this.$refs["input_" + id].focus();`, it's actually trying to set `focus` on a hidden element (because the current reference is not updated).

That's why you need to call the `$nextTick()` to update it. But if you wanted a quick fix to your problem, without calling `$nextTick()`, you could update it manually like this:

```
this.displayTitleInput = "inline-block"
this.$refs["input_" + id].style.display = this.displayTitleInput

this.$refs["input_" + id].focus();
```

This would also work :) Hope it helps!!

Comment: See the note [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) ~ _"When used on elements/components with `v-for`, the registered reference will be an **Array** containing DOM nodes or component instances."_

Comment: Yeah, that one threw me a little too :)

Comment: Oh!!!! Thank you so much!!! Put focus after displaying it! I see. You are smart!!!

Comment: @Phil Yes, I noticed the array now. It seems if you aren't using `v-for` it keeps the refs in an object. However, I'm afraid that your comment about `this` doesn't seem to be valid. It works perfectly here. https://jsfiddle.net/un65e9oc/7/

Comment: Ah, of course. Vue defaults the `$nextTick` [_`context`_ param](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to the current Vue instance.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to set focus after click on something and show input text box with set focus with vue js

```
directives: {
  focus: {
    // directive definition
    inserted: function (el) {
      el.focus()
    }
  }
}
```

and use custom directive for it. In case you need it should work on click then set with click

```
directives: {
  click: {
    // directive definition
    inserted: function (el) {
      el.focus()
    }
  }
}
```

and use it

```
<input v-focus> or <input v-click>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me when we validate the form and want to set dynamically focus on each field

```
           this.$validator.validateAll("FORM_NAME").then(valid => {

                var errors = this.$validator.errors;

                if (valid) {
                    console.log('All Fields are valid')
                } else {
                    const errorFieldName = this.$validator.errors.items[0].field;
                    console.log(errorFieldName);
                    this.$refs[errorFieldName].focus();
                }

            });
```